# Excel VBA Pivot Table Hide Fields with less than 5 characters

Tags: vba, pivot-table

My PC is a Mac and I am using Excel version 16.54. What I am trying to filter out are all the zips that have < 5 digits but can't quite get it. I presently have the filter removing my N/A values like so:

```
    Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Zip")
        With objField
            objField.PivotItems("N/A").Visible = False
            End With
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Are they numeric?

Comment: Loop through the `PivotItems` collection (see [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24243034/excel-vba-loop-through-pivot-items)) and check the `Len` of its `Name`property?

Comment: @Natthan_sav - Yes, they are numeric, though I wonder if I might encounter cases where the user inputs o in place of 0, in that case, it would no longer be numeric.
@Raymond Wu, would that be something like 

```For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
        If Len(pi) < 5 Then objField.PivotItems(<value>).Visible = False
    Next pi
```
Though, I'm not sure what to put for value.

Comment: Something like `For Each pi in pf.PivotItems: If Len(pi.Name) < 5 Then pi.Visible = False: Next pi`. `pi` is the `PivotItem` object. @Baiano42

Comment: If they are numeric, could you just apply a value filter for >9999 ?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav, Originally, I thought that would work too. Unfortunately, as there are some Zip codes that start with a 0, I'm not sure that that method would work...